# How to SUM using SQL?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
Project_Name    Start Date
P-2018-001      2018/06/20
P-2018-002      2018/06/21
P-2018-003      2018/06/22
```

Table 2:

```
Date        Project_Name    Staff   Working_Time
2018/06/20  P-2018-001      Staff01 8
2018/06/20  P-2018-002      Staff02 6
2018/06/21  P-2018-001      Staff03 9
2018/06/21  P-2018-003      Staff02 8
2018/06/21  P-2018-002      Staff01 9
2018/06/22  P-2018-003      Staff03 5
2018/06/22  P-2018-002      Staff01 7
2018/06/22  P-2018-001      Staff02 10
```

Expected Output:

```
Project_Name    Start Date  Staff01     Staff02     Staff03
P-2018-001      2018/06/20  8           10          9
P-2018-002      2018/06/21  16          6           0
P-2018-003      2018/06/22  0           8           5
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Share the code you wrote that did not produce your expected output

Comment: What's the expected result if suddenly Staff04 appears?

Comment: See the hover-text on the downvote arrow: _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like aggregation and a `join`:

```
select t2.project_name, t1.start_date,
       max(case when t2.Staff = 'Staff01' then t2.working_time else 0 end) as Staff01,
       max(case when t2.Staff = 'Staff02' then t2.working_time else 0 end) as Staff02,
       max(case when t2.Staff = 'Staff03' then t2.working_time else 0 end) as Staff03
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t1.project_name = t1.project_name
group by t2.project_name, t1.start_date;
```